# How can I make some methods only visible to two different classes?

Tags: java

I’ve got some encryption and decryption methods, and I want to be able to use them within two different classes.

But of course, I don’t want to make them public, as then they can be called by anyone? How can I make these methods just visible to two specific classes, and nowhere else.

**EDIT:** What if I cannot extend the class, since these other classes are already extending some other classes?

Comment: I'm not sure if you are implying that making something public or private makes it less secure?  It definitely does not, in any real sense.  Java class visibility options are not a 'language based security' solution.

Comment: But what I’m doing is encrypting user’s password for storage in the DB. This is via a function. If this function is visible, someone using the library could just look at the DB tables, and call the decrypt function themselves. But if this method is private, it can only be called within the code, thus not allowing it to be used by outsiders. This was kind-of my thinking... what is the correct solution in this regard?

Comment: No, it's definitely not the correct solution.  Method visibility is a namespace convenience.  The code is still in a running virtual machine - in memory on a real machine.  The database is still accessible directly.  You should assume that anybody can read what is in your database tables, and behave accordingly.  This mostly involves only ever storing encrypted passwords, or even better --- one-way cryptographic hashes of passwords.  If a 'decrypt' function exists anywhere (e.g., in the Java bytecode), then assume that a suitably motivated attacker can run it.

Comment: AspectJ can fulfill this use-case https://eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/adk15notebook/ataspectj-declare.html

Answer (score 2):

You need to create that method as protected and create those two class in the same package. and create other class in different package. As protected method is applicable to sub class which is in the same package. And also extend method class in the created 2 classes.

Comment: protected method can be accessed by subclasses in other packages also, no need of same package.

Comment: NO modifier is access only for that package so that would be good practive to create method as no modifier.

Comment: Thanks, but what happens if I cannot extend the class? As I am already extending another class?

Comment: you can not get access of super class members and methods.

Answer (score 2):

If the classes are part of the same package then you can make them package private (i.e. no modifier). "Package Private" or "Default Access" methods can only be used in the package that they are declared, and do not become part of the API of the class. You declare a method package private by putting no modifier on it's declaration.

```
Modifier    | Class | Package | Subclass | World

public      |  Y    |    Y    |    Y     |   Y

protected   |  Y    |    Y    |    Y     |   N

no modifier |  Y    |    Y    |    N     |   N

private     |  Y    |    N    |    N     |   N
```